# Only one system of equation has solution

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ real matrix. Show that only one of the following systems has solution:
>
> (I): $Ax > 0$
>
> (II): $Ay = 0, y \geq 0, y \neq \theta$, where $\theta$ is zero vector.

I have no idea to proceed the proof. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: It looks like Farka's Lemma, but it is not the same. By the way, you mentioned that $y \geq 0$. So what do you mean by that? Again there is a contradiction if I think you want to mean $y \geq \theta_n$, then you mentioned that $y \neq \theta_n$.

Comment: $y = (y_i)\geq 0$ iff $y_i\geq 0, \forall i$

Comment: Problem is probably ill-stated homework material. Looks like a random question thrown here to see what happens. Are you fuzzing stackexchange ?

Comment: I wonder if the second equation was meant to be $A^Ty = 0$, $y \geq 0$, $y \neq 0$, in which case the assertion would hold true by virtue of the fact that $N(A^T) = C(A)^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this problem is correct as stated. Consider the following counterexample.
Let

$$
A = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right],\quad
x = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
\end{array}\right], \quad\text{and}\quad 
y  
= \left[
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
\end{array}\right]
$$

Then $Ax > 0$ and $Ay = 0$, $y \geq 0$, $y \neq 0$, i.e., both systems have a solution.